# What's up with the red on green bubbles?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

I'm not colorblind, but these bubbles from the reputation summary / recent changes page are really pushing the envelope into "fugly". Could someone here have a word with the designers and see if they meant to enact this change?

Even yellow/purple or orange/blue is better for people that are colorblind if you really want to use contrasting / opposing colors for this...

[image: red on green]

Comment: This was not intended. We're fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my fault for assuming the text was white already on the other SE sites when adding this styling.  [Jin](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/jin) pushed a CSS update so that the text on these *is* now white everywhere, it should look much better now.

Edit - it looks MUCH better - so happy it was an oops (and a minor one at that.) Speedy fix FTW.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'll be tweaking the green to each site's proper green shade this weekend. For now, white text helps as a quick fix.

Comment: Very impressed by the speed of resolution. Thanks again to both of you, the apple site colors are very well done. Thanks @nick-craver and @jin